# ffmpeg audio stream map loses metadata

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, metadata

I'm trying to map audio streams directly from the input file to the output without touching them at all, but the output file loses any metadata they had before.

This command should just take the input file and perfectly copy it:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -codec copy -map 0 output.mp4
```

And it mostly does, except for the audio tracks losing names. It does seem it's trying to write them, as they show on the input file when ffmpeg starts and the output file contains this at the end:

```
Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x800 [SAR 1:1 DAR 12:5], q=2-31, 2564 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc (default)
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2018-06-14T16:15:51.000000Z
  handler_name    : VideoHandler
Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 256 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2018-06-14T16:15:51.000000Z
  handler_name    : Stereo
Stream #0:2(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 160 kb/s
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2018-06-14T16:15:51.000000Z
  handler_name    : Commentary
```

Thanks.

Comment: Looks to be a bug. Can you share a sample file?

Comment: @Gyan Sure - https://nofile.io/f/X8tdjeMkgXp/clip.mp4. Just 5 seconds from the start but it's still happening the same. I'm running a relatively recent build of ffmpeg (2018 at some time) so it's not an old bug if it is.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to get this patched within a few days.